# I Need better way To Hide SideNavigator from some routes and another not?

Tags: reactjs

I have used `useLocation` hook and it is already working but is there a better way so I need help and advice.

```js
location.pathname !== '/' &&
location.pathname !== '/offer-price' &&
location.pathname !== '/freelancer-offer' &&
location.pathname !== '/advertise-details'
  ? false
  : { SideNav }
```

Comment: what are you trying to do? can you give more details?

Comment: try to post your some of your code even if you obfuscate some methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an array of locations where you need to hide/show SideNav

```
const showSideNav = ['/', '/offer-price', '/freelancer-offer', '/advertise-details']

showSideNav.includes(location.pathname) ?  { SideNav } : false
```

Comment: thanx for help me @Eng.sojin